# Magnesium oxide lab question

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equipment

For my magnesium oxide lab, one of the question asks why I need to include the cover of the crucible when weighing it with the magnesium before the reaction, then again after with magnesium oxide, and in the beginning when its empty. Does it change if I don't include the cover? anyone have any hints or tips as to why I need to include the cover?

Answer (score 2):

When you burn magnesium it sputters. Without a cover bits would be thrown out. With the cover bits stick to the inside of the cover.

(1) Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium) - Weight(crucible+lid) = Weight(magnesium)

(2) Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium oxide) - Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium) = Weight(oxygen)

Comment: The question is asking why you want to cover when weighing it. Not during the experiment

Comment: Think... if there is magnesium oxide on the inside of the cover from burning, what happens if you ignore the cover in the initial and final weighings?

Answer (score 1):

Magnesium is going to be covered with a thin layer of $\ce{MgO}$ and is not really an issue here, but for calcined $\ce{MgO}$ you need to avoid both physical absorption and chemisorption of water vapors and $\ce{CO2}$ from the air:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{MgO + H2O &-> Mg(OH)2}\\
\ce{MgO + CO2 &-> MgCO3}
\end{align}
$$

Both magnesium hydroxide and carbonate are also hygroscopic and form a wide range of hydrates when kept in humid environment. It is necessary either to weigh the sample very quickly, or use the crucible with the lid tightly closed.

Ideally for such measurements you want to use a [weighing bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_bottle) specifically designed for precise mass determination of hygroscopic and reactive solids:

[image: Weighing bottles of various sizes]
([Source](http://www.baltalab.lv/en/Weighing-bottle))

In both cases make sure to tare the balance with both masses of the vessel and the lid beforehand in order to subtract those values from the experimental data. Of course, if you label the vessels, this also should be done prior to weighting when the crucible is cooled down to the room temperature.

Comment: How does the water vapor and CO2 cause the need to weigh the crucible with the lid closed? Does it not work if  you dont measure it with the lid?

Comment: Baloney. The crucible lid is not air tight.

Comment: @ChemPsycho I added some more details. If you want to make a good use of analytical balance, you got to weight air-sensitive substances with the lid closed.

Comment: @MaxW It's not airtight, but it a) minimizes the contact of the substance with the atmosphere of the entire room; b) develops a habit to properly handle air-sensitive substances. I guess this is a teaching lab, where stuff get shattered quite often, and crucibles are generally less expensive than weighing bottles.

Comment: Why would u want this to be air tight. Oxygen has to go in to mix with magnesium

Comment: @ChemPsycho When you *weigh* substances, you *do not* want stuff to react with anything.

Comment: What would it react to if there was no lid? co2?

Comment: @ChemPsycho your question is unclear. The way I interpret it is that you are trying to weigh the MgO product which you *already obtained from a reaction previously.* However, your comments here make no sense in that context, so I guess I was wrong? The problem is that nobody can accurately guess at what you mean by "my magnesium oxide lab", as nobody has your lab book with them. Would you care to elaborate by editing your question?

Comment: Edited my question to make it more answerable.

Comment: @ChemPsycho I edited the answer a bit to address new edit; however, in the nutshell it's still the same idea.

Comment: Im in a 10th grade honors chem class. Don't understand u

Comment: @ChemPsycho What *exactly* you don't understand?

Comment: I still dont understand why u need to cover the crucible when weighing it before you put in the magnesium ribbon, then after you put in the magnesium ribbon and weigh again, then weight again of magnesium oxide after heating

Comment: @ChemPsycho Again, you want the masses of pure substances only. To prevent the unwanted side reactions, you limit the contact with the atmosphere by putting the substance in a closed vessel. What the side processes are is quite explicitly explained in the answer. If you still have no idea what's going on, you might want to do some additional readings on basic chemistry, or talk to you technical assistant.

Comment: Again baloney. (1) Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium) -Weight(crucible+lid) = Weight(magnesium) (2) Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium oxide) -Weight(crucible+lid+magnesium) = Weight(oxygen) // As I said, you need the lid to contain the magnesium oxide within the crucible and lid. Without the lid you'd lose some of the magnesium oxide.